# Правильный период времени

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл, периоды-времени

Каким образом определяется срок в этой фразе?
**С 2019 года сроком на три последующие года.**

Answer (score 1):

Если по тексту, то срок отсчитывается **от** даты подразумеваемого *события* в 2019 году **до** *той же* даты в 2022 году. Можно предположить, что до 2019 года срок, измеряемый количеством лет, был другим (отличался от 3 лет).